# Espaçamento entre tbodys

Tags: html, css, table

Tenho uma tabela de listagem de itens com grupos de linhas (tbody) e gostaria de adicionar espaçamento entre eles, não que já não tenha feito, mas venho procurando uma forma "menos gambiarra" de alcançar o feito.

Também gostaria de estilizar de uma forma melhor as bordas da tabela enquanto consigo o espaçamento. A seguir um exemplo da tabela:

**Exemplo**

```css
table { text-align:left; border-collapse:separate; border-spacing:0; }

table tbody { border-spacing:0 10px; } /* apenas ilustrativo */

table tbody td { vertical-align:middle; border-top:1px solid #000; }
table tbody:nth-child(odd) { background-color:#ccc; }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>th1</th>
      <th>th2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1</td>
      <td>Teste</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Algum conteúdo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">2</td>
      <td>Teste</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Algum conteúdo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**Para quem nunca viu uma tabela com mútiplos <tbody>, aí vai uma boa pedida:**
https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/irregular/

Answer (score 1):

Defina um width para a tabela um float:left e uma margin-bottom para o tbody.

Comment: Interessante, funciona, porém a estruturação de colunas da tabela é perdida, `tbody` fica como se fosse a primeira coluna a esquerda na tabela.

Answer (score 0):

**Espaçamento**

Para dar o espeçamento basta atribuir o `padding` serve para dar um espeçamento interno

```
table tbody { padding: 10px; }
```

**Estilo Borda**

```
table { 
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #CCC;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

table:hover { 
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #999;
}
```